# Allocate global pointer inside function

Tags: c, memory-management

I am trying to initialize a global pointer inside a function. This is an example that shows the same issue:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

int* global = NULL;

void alloc(int* p) {
  p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
  *p = 42;
}

int main() {
  alloc(global);
  assert(global);
}
```

After the call to `alloc` `global` is still `NULL`. It works if I don't pass `global` to the function but just use it since it's global.

I would rather keep the function call this way to make it more clear. Is there a way to achieve this? Thanks.

Btw. I'm using gcc 6.3.1

Comment: `int *alloc() {
  p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
  *p = 42; return p;
}`

Comment: You should read your C text book again. Focus on passing function parameters by value or by reference. You only change a copy of global within your function.

Comment: there's a ton of duplicates of that one.

Comment: @Gerhardh: Thanks, that solved my problem.

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Thanks for the advice